# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data'), map is not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a API this is working fine in console. but when I'm using map this is not working giving error.

Getting this error:-
[image]

**My Code:-**

```js
function GetEgyptStates() {
  const [egyptData, setEgyptData] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/states-and-districts.json').then((response) => {
      setEgyptData(response.data);
      console.log(response.data.Egypt.Assuit);
    });
  }, []);

  if (!egyptData) return null;

  return (
    <div>
        {egyptData.response.data.Egypt.Assuit.map((item) => (
          <li>{item}</li>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

ThankYou for your Support!

Comment: Could you please provide the full error message? Hard to tell which part is not working without it.

Comment: I added error in questions.

Comment: Seems like you need to remove `response.data` in the 6th to last line, and try `egyptData.Egypt.Assuit.map`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   function GetEgyptStates() {
  const [egyptData, setEgyptData] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:3000/states-and-districts.json').then((response) => {
      setEgyptData(response.data);
      console.log(response.data.Egypt.Assuit);
    });
  }, []);

  if (!egyptData) return null;

  return (
    <div>
        {egyptData.Egypt.Assuit.map((item) => (
          <li>{item}</li>
        ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Try this. You are already setting the response data using **response.data** in state therefor you don't need to use **response.data** again

Further, if this doesn't work, then please post a screenshot of api response from console in question.

Thanks,